# area of part of sphere inside cylinder

Tags: vector-analysis

Question is to find area of part of sphere of radius $a$ centered at origin that lies inside cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$.

By drawing figure I thought it is exactly half part of sphere so answer must be $2\pi a^2$ but actual answer has one additional term $-4a^2$. From where this term come?

Comment: You didn't draw it good, it is quite less than half

Comment: yes,i understand the graph and try again but still can't get to the answer.

Comment: As you didn't show your work, we can't tell where you went wrong.  I suspect you completed the square incorrectly, which led to drawing the wrong figure.  Note that $(2\pi-4)a^2$ is far less than half the area of the sphere.  You should post your figure and explain how you came up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the figure:

[image]

The request volume is less than an half sphere.  This is a classical exercize an I think that you can solve it starting from this symilar ( a bit more general) example: [Calculate the volume of the solid bounded laterally.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208721/calculate-the-volume-of-the-solid-bounded-laterally/2209203#2209203)

Answer (score 0):

It looks something like this

[image]

You can integrate it with x going from $0$ to $a$, making slices of the area. Each slice has width of $dx\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ and length of $2x\arcsin{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}$

$\int_0^a\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}2x\arcsin{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}dx$

putting $x=a\cos t$ it becomes

$\int_0^{\pi/2}2a^2\cos ttdt=2a^2((t\sin t+\cos t)|_0^{\pi/2}=a^2(\pi-2)$

EDIT this was one area, upper for example, so just multiply by 2. It is $P=2a^2(\pi-2)$

Comment: I was doing problem by using formula of surface area where we explicitly represent z in terms of x and y.Then i took xy projection and convert it to polar coordinates so my limits were 0<r<a cos(theta) and (-pi/2)<theta<(pi/2).but I am getting wrong answer after several attempts by this method.why so?

Comment: i want to show my work but don't know how i can put all those terms.From where i can learn how to use LATEX.